# how to install php 5.4 install on ubuntu desktop 12.04?

Tags: php, ubuntu

I try to install php5 package with a specific version 5.4.

But I have problem and can not solve it myself. When I try to install :

```
"apt-get install php5=5.4.9-4ubuntu2"
```

It returns me an error:

> E: Version '5.4.9-4ubuntu2' for 'php5' was not found.

How can I solve this task?

Answer (score 36):

Add this ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Then update and upgrade, upgrade will automatically install latest 5.4.x version of php

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Followed by,

`sudo apt-get install -y php5.6`

or

`sudo apt-get install -y php7.2`

depending on which version of PHP you want installed.

---

To install through Ubuntu software centre

## [php5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php5) [image: Install php5]

<sub>(source: [ubuntu.com](https://apps.ubuntu.com/assets/images/download_ubuntu.png))</sub>

Ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-latest-php-in-supported-ubuntu-versions-like-5-4-x-in-ubuntu-1

Comment: I have found the answer here: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5 to install 5.4 you have to load                    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable and sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade. THANKS!!!

Comment: Use Igor Khromov ppa, but use this command for update:  apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y

Comment: I have found thi other answer more complete in my opinion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018626/add-apt-repository-not-found

Comment: I followed the instructions (and used php5-oldstable) and it still installs PHP 5.5. Any ideas...?

Comment: same for me - installs PHP 5.5.6

Comment: command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5` produces error: `Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~ondrej/+archive/php5) to get PPA information, please check your internet connection.`

Comment: Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~ondrej/ubuntu/php5'.
The user named '~ondrej' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/php5'

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still looking to install php 5.4 and wants to create a stand-alone install of php 5.4 from source, this is how do do it:

Create a folder named php-5.4 in your local home directory like ~/programs/php-5.4. Then execute below commands from it through CLI.

```
  sudo apt-get install gcc libmysqlclient-dev libxml2-dev
  wget --trust-server-names http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.4.15.tar.bz2
  tar xjf php-5.4.15.tar.bz2
  cd php-5.4.15
  ./configure --prefix=$PWD/installdir --enable-bcmath --with-mysql
  make install
  cd -
```

Replace 5.4.15 with the latest old-stable version of php.
Refer [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/installinglinux#PHP) Google appengine developer page for more details.

**edit**

Updated the new location for php 5.4.

Comment: wget responds with ERROR 404: Not found - seems the file is no longer hosted at the URL specified ..

Comment: @AndyLorenz Thanks for informing! Since PHP 5.4 has reached EOL, it is only available on museum.php.net now. I've updated the location in the answer accordingly.

Comment: that's great Prahlad, and thanks for updating your post.  It would really help me (and possibly others reading this) if you could confirm how to "point" the server at this php version once its installed (at the moment my server doesn't even know its got a thing called php ...)  many thanks

Comment: You can get the last minor version with `curl http://museum.php.net/php5/ 2>/dev/null | grep ">php-5.4.*.tar.bz2" | cut -d'.' -f 3 | sort -g | tail -1`

Comment: Whats then guys ? i did such php install and **how i can connect apache and php 5.4** ? all articles are for standard php switch,  not for meuseum php installs

Comment: checking whether libxml build works... no
configure: error: build test failed.  Please check the config.log for details.