# How to install php musesum version with apache and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, apache, php-5.3

I'm having trouble with installing old **php 5.3.29** on ubuntu 16.04

Recently I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003819/how-to-install-php-5-4-install-on-ubuntu-desktop-12-04/20883024#answer-20883024) useful source on how to install old unsupported php versions which are available only in php museum

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install make

# php museum version installation
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc libmysqlclient-dev libxml2-dev
wget --trust-server-names http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.3.29.tar.bz2
tar xjf php-5.3.29.tar.bz2
cd php-5.3.29
./configure --prefix=$PWD/installdir --enable-bcmath --with-mysql 
sudo make install
```

**Now I need to connect apache2 and php 5.3.29 but how ?? (how to configure Apache to use php from custom directory)**

All the articles I found talk about how to switch php version use `update-alternatives --config php`. That command ignores my php5.3 installed in the custom folder by make command.

I even tried to symlink php executable file to /usr/bin

ln -s /home/ubuntu/php-5.3.29/installdir/bin/php /usr/bin/php5.3.29

and again no luck with update-alternatives command run

Answer (score 1):

Hmm found another way (adding ppa repo) solution for this issue here:

https://everton.rocks/conteudo/multiple-php-versions-apache

```
# add this 2 lines to /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/sergey-dryabzhinsky/php53/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/sergey-dryabzhinsky/php53/ubuntu xenial main 

sudo apt update
sudo apt install php53-apache2
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo a2enmod php53
sudo service apache2 restart
```